# Ignore CSRF Protection for doActionFor of workflow on Script Python on Plone 5

Tags: plone

I'm trying to do a workflow transition using Script Python.

Like this:

```
wtool = context.portal_workflow
obj = context.Plone.doc1
wtool.doActionFor(obj, 'publish')
obj.reindexObject()
```

But I got confirm page. This page title is `Confirming User Action`.

I think this is auto function of CSRF protection. Please let me know. Ignoring the protection for my script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I imagine your script is called from a link. You need to change the way your script is called:

- either call it as a POST in a form (plone.protect will automatically add the authenticator token to your form),
- either add the token in the querystring in your link (See http://docs.plone.org/develop/addons/upgrade_to_50.html?highlight=protect#csrf-protection )

Comment: Very Thank you! I could run my script.

Comment: I made another Script for call url.

`
   authenticator = context.restrictedTraverse("@@authenticator")
   url ="/Plone/portal_skins/custom/wf_tool_" + "?_authenticator="  + authenticator.token()
   context.REQUEST.RESPONSE.redirect(url)
`